# How do I write effects for actions in ngrx/data?

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-data

I work in a project with ngrx, also using other libraries & packages from ngrx like ngrx/entity or ngrx/data.

*Sometimes* I need to *create effects* in *certains actions* *belonging* (in terms of being dispatched) to ngrx/data.

Where I find some difficulties is dispatching other actions with strong dependencies of some other actions dispatched by ngrx/data in an automatic way or even by myself (custom) like below

...

```
    @Injectable()
    export class FooEffects {

        fooSelected$ = createEffect(() =>
            this.actions$
                .pipe(
                    ofType(FooActions.fooSelected),
                    map((action) => this.entityActionFactory.create<Foo>('Foo', EntityOp.QUERY_LOAD),
                  ))
);
       ...

        constructor(private actions$: Actions, private entityActionFactory: EntityActionFactory) { }

    }
```

...

So, how do I listen Actions in ngrx/data like QUERY_LOAD, the common get/all or any other else to achieve the creation of new effects? 
Does it exist something like

```
fooNgrxDataEffectForQueryLoad$ = createEffect(() =>
            this.actions$
                .pipe(
                    ofType(('Foo', EntityOp.QUERY_LOAD)),
```

Or asked in another way, **how do I write effects for "*NATIVE*" actions in ngrx/data**?

I know ngrx/data was created to get rid off from of Actions, Selectors, Effects, Reducers as much as it is possible, having therefore less boilerplate. However, there should be a way to create effects from ngrx/data.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: is this your article? https://betterprogramming.pub/write-effects-for-actions-in-ngrx-data-214c93869758

Comment: Yes, I wrote it regarding to this question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ofEntityType](https://ngrx.io/api/data/ofEntityType) and [ofEntityOp](https://ngrx.io/api/data/ofEntityOp) pipeable operators to write effects for NgRx Data actions.  So, in your example above, you could say:

```
 fooNgrxDataEffectForQueryLoad$ = createEffect(() =>
            this.actions$
                .pipe(
                    ofEntityType('Foo'),
                    ofEntityOp(EntityOp.QUERY_LOAD)),
```

Looks like the OP answered his own question in this article as well: https://betterprogramming.pub/write-effects-for-actions-in-ngrx-data-214c93869758

Comment: Exactly, I did heh...Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have in your example is one of possible ways.

You should listen on actions of ngrx/data type and cause stuff you need.
ngrx/data is quite raw and has [a lot of limitations](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/limitations).

What they recommend is [to extend base classes and to change behavior there](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/extension-points) adding new actions / effects / reducers etc.

Would be nice if you could provide an example of how you want to change the flow.

Comment: I appreciate your answer :), but sorry if I explained myself not very good...The main question was "how do I do effects for actions in ngrx/data". Thx

Comment: Ah. The same as you wrote above. The goal of Nrgx/data is to get rid of mess of actions effects and reducers via provided services. If you want to extend one - you need extend a base class and override its methods. Or you can do like you have in your question - listen on these effects types and do own stuff. Might you give an example of what you would like to do in an effect with ngrx data?

Comment: Updated my answer with the same things as in the comment.